# No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'. for mat-select?

Tags: angular

I have a form element:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select
   #ref="ngModel"
   [required]="true"
   (selectionChange)="selectDocumentType($event)"
   placeholder="Выбрать"
   >
   <mat-option *ngFor="let type of typedocuments" [value]="type.typeid">{{
   type.typename
   }}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   <mat-error *ngIf="ref.touched && !ref.valid">
      <div *ngIf="ref.errors.required">Поле обязательно для заполнения</div>
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I try to use template reference: `#ref="ngModel"`

Then to show errors:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="ref.touched && !ref.valid">
```

Why I get this error:

> No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'.

Comment: I think problem that there is no [ngModel] attribute, but I dont need it

Comment: Did you imported `FormsModule` ?

Comment: Yes, I have imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `#ref="ngModel"` with `ngModel`.
Try this

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    [ngModel]="myData"
    #ref="ngModel"
    [required]="true"
    (selectionChange)="selectDocumentType($event)"
    placeholder="Выбрать"
  >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let type of typedocuments" [value]="type.typeid">{{
      type.typename
      }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="ref.touched && !ref.valid">
    <div *ngIf="ref.errors.required">Поле обязательно для заполнения</div>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

In component define `myData`

```
export class MyComponent{
myData = '';
...
}
```